# Back up website with Notepad++

Tags: html, website, hosting, backup, web-hosting

I have a lot of files on my website right now, and I'd like to back them all up to my computer. I'm using Notepad++'s FTP plugin, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to mass backup everything, or if there is another free FTP program that would do this for me?

Comment: Notepad++ is a _text editor._ Despite its FTP capability, it is _not a backup program._

Answer (score 3):

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a great free opensource FTP client (and server). Windows has a built-in FTP client, which can be run from the command-line and [scripted with batch files](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=96269).

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is rsync and/or rdiff-backup.  Set up a cronjob (or scheduled task in Windows, whatever) to do it automatically.  It's very important to automate backups.